# Error loading theme, cannot find "theme.css" resource of "primefaces-admin" library

Tags: java-ee

Estou tentando trocar o tema do primedace par o Adminfaces mas agora esta acontencendo este erro

> Error loading theme, cannot find "theme.css" resource of
>   "primefaces-admin" library

Comment: Esse theme.css está sendo chamado em algum xhtml ?

Comment: Posta também o seu arquivo web.xml